# Link to resources such as css and javascript files

Tags: xhtml, asp.net-mvc-2

How can I link to resources such as css and javascript files? My default project is using links like ../../Content/styles.css. How can I do something like ~/content/styles.css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= Url.Content("~/content/styles.css") %>" 
    type="text/css" />

<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/content/scripts/file.js") %>" 
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave out the ~.  "/Content/styles.css"